# Making an app that reads values from serial and make phone calls

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller

I would love to know if there is a way to make an app on an android phone or IOS, that receives a signal from a micro controller through serial(cable,USB, or even Bluetooth) to push the phone to make calls.
The idea behind this is that I don't want to waste money on buying GSM/GPRS module while people already have sell-phones. So for example, whenever a button is pressed (that is connected to an arduino for example) the paired cell phone calls a certain person.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Try [this](http://goo.gl/g1iftQ). Same general idea. Hopefully this will give you the jumpstart you need.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right you can look  at this tutorial.
http://www.geekylemon.com/xcode-phone-calls